# Given a list of color objects, find the most/least frequently existing color, and return that as a color object

Tags: c#, linq, graphics, colors, bitmap

Currently I have a list of `Color` objects. The format of each are `RGB` format, which means, for example, `0, 0, 0` would be the color black.

I am interested in looping through this list and do sort-of a histogram of it. Find out the most frequently appearing color and the lowest frequently existing color. A question I have is how do I bin color values? Given a list of doubles, you can bin the values through finding its range, and then dividing it by how many bins you want. Not sure how one could achieve that through `Color` objects.

A piece of code I have currently have uses LINQ:

```
            var cs = new List<Color> { 
                Color.White, 
                Color.Black 
            };

            var max = cs.OrderByDescending(x => (0.2125 * x.R) + (0.7154 * x.G) + (0.0721 * x.B)).Last();
```

It takes my list of colors, and finds the "max" value of that list, and outputs either `White` or `Black`, depending on whether the output is max or min.

All in all I am interested in a `.Mode()` method for a list of colors.

Comment: `All in all I am interested in a .Mode() method for a list of colors` - Just FYI, C# has this concept of [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx), where you can create static methods and use them just as if they were regular instance methods defined in the target type, while leaving the type untouched. So, when you find the answer for your question, you might want to encapsulate that in an extension and then use like: `var result = cs.Mode();` or the like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For calculating mode try `ToLookup` with ordering:

```
var ordered = cs.ToLookup(c => c).OrderByDescending(c => c.Count()).First().Key;
```

**Update:**

You can create an extension method as well:

```
public static Color Mode(this IEnumerable<Color> colors)
{
     return colors.ToLookup(c => c).OrderByDescending(c => c.Count()).First().Key;
}
```

Comment: Hi devMachine. What if my List of colors is defined as `IEnumerable<Color> colors`?

Comment: Would I just do `var ordered = colors.ToLookup...`

Comment: @theGreenCabbage most LINQ extensions actually target `IEnumerable<T>` - therefore can be applied on any sorts of lists and collections such as `List<T>`, `Collection<T>`, etc, and even interface-typed variables such as `IEnumerable<stuff> myvar;`

Comment: Thank you. Another quick question - I am assuming `ordered` returns a `color` object?

Comment: Good point. I updated the answer, it lacked `.Key` at the end.

Comment: Hi devMarchine. One small issue - it seems after I use your extension method, I get the error called "extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class" in my main class on compiling. However, it also appears if I remove the `this` from the input, I get rid of the error. I don't think that's a major issue is there? I mean, the graph looks perfect. No matter what type of range of colors I throw at it it finds the perfect background color every time.

Comment: Okay, I assume you injected my extension method to your Color class. It works after you remove 'this' keyword as you mentioned. You may also want to create a special class for extension helpers like ColorHelpers, make it static and copy my proposed method into it (without deleting 'this' keyword).